# Facebook Messenger Location in nodeJs

Tags: node.js, facebook, facebook-messenger

I have setup the facebook bot, and everything except the location sending. I am unable to receive the location of a user either through the quick_reply button, or the normal sending location through messenger. I am getting this as my output in my heroku logs:

"attachments":[{"title":"Attachment Unavailable","url":null,"type":"fallback","payload":null}]

But, the location is sent properly, and I can click on it and it opens up and shows the right location. How do I fix this?

Comment: facing the same issue @Soccergods. if u resend the same location as attachment to the bot, it works interestingly.

Comment: For me, it sometimes sends the right location. But 95% it is attachment unavailable. Did you figure out any work around?

Comment: Not yet ! Is there any forum for messenger developers to raise this ?

Comment: There is facebook developers community. I posted there, and will tell you if I get it fixed.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Looking forward.

Comment: It seems like it is a bug with facebook itself. Do you know if we can raise an issue officially to facebook? A lot of people are having this problem in the past few days apparently

Comment: Looks like te Fix is ready

Comment: Raised it here - https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/2185120575045712/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was just a recognised bug by Facebook  itself, and they said that they resolved it and that the patch should be out ASAP(they said this on 22/12/2016). There was no error in code :)